# Debian [Squeeze] Server - wake on lan not working

Tags: linux, debian, wake-on-lan

I am searching for some help on the following issue:

**Problem Summary**

Debian Server should wake on lan. Utilities installed, BIOS adjusted, startup scripts adjusted. Trying to wake up from state of hibernation/suspense/halt from linux mint client machine - no response from server.

---

**Physical Setup**

- (S ) Debian Server (Squeeze, up to date) hosting Samba, MySQL, Apache & SSH servers
- (C1) Client: Desktop pc running linux mint 17, up to date
- (C2) Client: Laptop - fedora 20
- (C3) Client: Raspberry Pi - XBMC media center
- (Cx) Client: External PCs logging onto server via SSH

All machines (except Cx) are in the same network. S, C1, C3 use wired connections.

**Server Specs**

- OS: Linux debbi 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 i686 GNU/Linux (per: *uname -a*)
- RAM: 6GB
- ~2.4 Ghz i686 processor
- ASUS P5B deluxe motherboard
- relevant interface: eth0
- no iptables set during trial face, but will follow later once WOL is set up

**Intension**

Have server S shutdown/hibernate after certain period of inactivity to save energy (my electricity bill has spiked ever since i have the server running).
Wake server if there is a new request.

**Steps so far**

I have been trying to gather information on the internet on how to accomplish this. The best summary of my steps so far can be found [here](https://www.lisenet.com/2013/set-up-wake-on-lan-wol-on-a-debian-wheezy-server/).

According tho [this](http://board.gulli.com/thread/717597-asus-p5b-deluxe-wake-or-lan/) and the manual, the AUS P5B Deluxe MB has 2 BIOS sections that need to be adjusted if WOL should be enabled: "Power on PCI/PCIe" and "LAN option ROM".
Both options were set to "enabled".

Installed ethtool and set the wol option to "g" using *ethtool -s eth0 wol g*

Here is the output of *ethtool eth0*

```
Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: No
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
MDI-X: Unknown
Supports Wake-on: pg
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
               drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
Link detected: yes
```

I also added a startup script using *update-rc.d* that calls *ethtool -s eth0 wol g*.
According to the website above, I also modified /etc/network/interfaces, which now looks like this

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
/sbin/ethtool -s eth0 wol g
```

**Problem**

Now if I hibernate/suspend S using the *pm-utils* (different problem - but using those the video signal gets distorted greatly on boot up, and on pm-suspend the server cannot recover when booting up again), or simply using *halt*, and deploy any of the following commands from C1

```
wakeonlan -p 7 -i 192.168.xxx.xx 00:ab:cd:ef:gh:11
wakeonlan -i 192.168.xxx.xx  00:ab:cd:ef:gh:11
wakeonlan 00:ab:cd:ef:gh:11
sudo etherwake 00:ab:cd:ef:gh:11
```

I do not get any response from the server. After manual boot up, *ethtool eth0*
confirms that the wol option is still set to "g".

---

**Questions**

1. Given the description above, do you see any obvious mistakes or something I forgot that would cause server S not to wake up ?
2. Are there any commands I could run to identify the problems ?

**This was a lot of information**. Thanks for reading through it. Looking forward to your answers !

---

**Additional Information/Quesions**

As you can see from the output of *ethtool eth0*, the chipset only supports wake on magicPacket and wake on activity (p + g options). As I need to be able to login from outside the network as well, I was thinking of using another RaspPi to act as a gateway for requests to the server. Using port forwarding the Pi could identify requests dedicated to the server S and then send the magicPacket to wake it up.

Would there be a better/ leaner way to do that ?

The server itself should go to sleep after a certain period of inactivity. I was planning to run a script every few minutes using the *netstat* commands to check port connections, writing results to a table and then calculating the period of inactivity. 
**Problem** here is that my desktop C1 is constantly connected to the samba server, but barely using it. Is there a command that lets me monitor the port including the nbr of outgoing packets ?

Last one: Does anyone know/have experience with the boot up problems after using the pm-utils ?